# Alert the user about app exit

Tags: iphone

I have and app using location updates. I need to notify user once the app is killed from background, manually or by OS.

Is there any way that I can show an alert to the user that the app is not running now. Is there any tweak? Please help.

Comment: Firing a local notification in `applicationWillTerminate:` is one option. Alert, not so much.

Comment: are you 100% sure  it will fire always? it failed for me multiple times